# Definition of an ultra pre-filter

Tags: convergence-divergence

I have come across the term "ultra prefilter" which has two possible definitions (that I can think of).  I tried googling this first I swear! (but google thinks I'm looking for filtered water or a water purifier)

The two most obvious meanings to assign to *an ultra prefilter $F$ on a space $X$*

- $F$ is a prefilter on $X$ which is not properly contained in any other prefilter on $X$
- $F$ is a prefilter on $X$ which is equivalent to any of its refinements

The first one is simply the definition of an ultra filter applied to a prefilter instead.  However the second one seems more appropriate, but I wanted to confirm it before I trust it too deeply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ultra prefilter is a prefilter, such that all supersets of the prefilter form an ultrafilter. That is, it is a filter base of an ultrafilter. You can take a look at 5.2. in Pete L. Clark's [notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/convergence.pdf) on convergence.

Comment: Those are indeed the notes I am working through, but I couldn't find a definition for ultra prefilter.  As for your answer, I understand everything after the "That is," part.  But before that, can you clarify exactly what needs to form a filter?  The set of all supersets of sets *in* the prefilter *always* forms a filter I think.

Comment: @Kyle: That was a typo. They are supposed to form an *ultra*filter. The terminology is not standard. The definition of a prefilter comes right after Proposition 5.5. on page 19. The conventions for how to relate filter-concepts and prefilter-concepts is on page 20.

Comment: It's funny, I know exactly what paragraph you are referring to when you mention the "conventions", I remember the paragraph exactly, yet I didn't make the connection.....

Thanks for the answer!